# using cocos2d to design shootgame, i can't invoke stopGame method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void)spriteMoveFinishedid)sender    //when sprite is outside of screen,it's deleted;
｛
     CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;
     if (sprite.tag == 1)    //it's enemy;
    {  
        escapeNum++;
       [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
        if (escapeNum == 10) 
        {
            [self stopGameEx];   //Because the speed of every enemy isn't same to other and there are bullets,it maybe happens that two sprites disappear at the same time, and the program stop at this with error --- program received signal：“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”。
        }
      //...........
    }
｝
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Can you add the codes in the function stopGameEx as well?

Comment: Yes，I can. But it can't run into the function stopGameEx at the most time, and if run into once or twice, the program is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside if loop, change sprite tag to mark it as expired sprite, and some where else remove.

```
enum
{
   kTagExpiredSprite = 999 //any number not ur sprite tag(1)
};
```

.....

```
-(void)spriteMoveFinishedid)sender    //when sprite is outside of screen,it's deleted;
｛
     CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;
     if (sprite.tag == 1)    //it's enemy;
    {  
        escapeNum++;
       sprite.tag = kTagExpiredSprite;
        if (escapeNum == 10) 
        {
            [self stopGameEx];   //Because the speed of every enemy isn't same to other and there are bullets,it maybe happens that two sprites disappear at the same time, and the program stop at this with error --- program received signal：“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”。
        }
      //...........
    }
｝
```

Comment: I'm sorry i had forgot it so long. Thanks all the time.